# Performance Cost of Profiling a Web-Application in Production

Tags: java, language-agnostic, profiling, production-environment, visualvm

I am attempting to solve performance issues with a large and complex tomcat java web application. The biggest issue at the moment is that, from time to time, the memory usage spikes and the application becomes unresponsive. I've fixed everything I can fix with log profilers and Bayesian analysis of the log files. I'm considering running a profiler on the production tomcat server.

**A Note to the Reader with Gentle Sensitivities:**

I understand that some may find the very notion of profiling a production app offensive. Please be assured that I have exhausted most of the other options. The reason I am considering this is that I do not have the resources to completely duplicate our production setup on my test server, and I have been unable to cause the failures of interest on my test server.

**Questions:**

I am looking for answers which work either for a java web application running on tomcat, or answer this question in a language agnostic way.

- What are the performance costs of profiling?
- Any other reasons why it is a bad idea to remotely connect and profile a web application in production (strange failure modes, security issues, etc)?
- How much does profiling effect the memory foot print?
- Specifically are there java profiling tools that have very low performance costs?
- Any java profiling tools designed for profiling web applications?
- Does anyone have benchmarks on the performance costs of profiling with visualVM?
- What size applications and datasets can visualVM scale to?

Comment: Would you happen to have Apache FOP in your Webapp?

Comment: I don't believe so, why does that cause memory issues?

Comment: FOP renders XML-based documents to PDF and other similar formats.  The version current in '09 used memory proportional to the size of the document while processing causing symptoms like what you describe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net) and its ancestor [DPCI](http://www-plan.cs.colorado.edu/diwan/7135/p357-anderson.pdf) were developed for profiling production systems.  The overhead for these is very low, and they profile your *full system*, including the kernel, so you can find performance problems in the VM *and* in the kernel and libraries.

To answer your questions:

1. **Overhead:** These are *sampled* profilers, that is, they generate timer or [performance counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) interrupts at some regular interval, and they take a look at what code is currently executing.  They use that to build a histogram of where you spend your time, and the overhead is very low (1-8% is what [they claim](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/)) for reasonable sampling intervals.

   Take a look at [this graph](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/performance/) of sampling frequency vs. overhead for OProfile.  You can tune the sampling frequency for lower overhead if the defaults are not to your liking.
2. **Usage in production:** The only caveat to using OProfile is that you'll need to install it on your production machine.  I believe there's kernel support in Red Hat since RHEL3, and I'm pretty sure other distributions support it.
3. **Memory:** I'm not sure what the exact memory footprint of OProfile is, but I believe it keeps relatively small buffers around and dumps them to log files occasionally.
4. **Java:** OProfile includes profiling agents that support Java and that are aware of code running in JITs.  So you'll be able to see Java calls, not just the C calls in the interpreter and JIT.
5. **Web Apps:** OProfile is a system-level profiler, so it's not aware of things like sessions, transactions, etc. that a web app would have.

   That said, it is a *full-system* profiler, so if your performance problem is caused by bad interactions between the OS and the JIT, or if it's in some third-party library, you'll be able to see that, because OProfile profiles the kernel and libraries.  This is an advantage for production systems, as you can catch problems that are due to misconfigurations or particulars of the production environment that might not exist in your test environment.
6. **VisualVM:** Not sure about this one, as I have no experience with VisualVM

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-oprof.html) on using OProfile to find performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

I've used YourKit to profile apps in a high-load production environment, and while there was certainly an impact, it was easily an acceptable one.  Yourkit [makes a big deal](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/overhead.jsp) of being able to do this in a non-invasive manner, such as selectively turning off certain profiling features that are more expensive (it's a sliding scale, really).

My favourite aspect of it is that you can run the VM with the YourKit agent running, and it has zero performance impact. it's only when you connect the GUI and start profiling that it has an effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in profiling production apps. If you work on distributed applications, there are times when a outofmemory exception occurs in a very unique probability scenario which is very difficult to reproduce in a dev/stage/uat environment.

You can try using custom profilers but if you are in a hurry and plugging in/ setting upa profiler on a production box will take time, you can also use the jvm to take a memory dump(jvms memory dump also gives you thread dump)

1. You can activate the automatic generation on the JVM command line, by using the following option :
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
2. he Eclipse Memory Analyzer project has a very powerful feature called “group by value”, which makes it possible to build an object query and regroup the instances by a field value. This is useful in the case where you have a lot of instances that are containing a smaller set of possible values, and you can to see which values are being used the most. This has really helped me understand some complex memory dumps so I recommend you try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider using one of the modern HotSpot JVM - Java Flight Recorder and [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html). It is a set of tools that allow you to collect low-level runtime information with the CPU overhead about 5% (I cannot prove the last statement anyhow, this is the statement of Oracle engineer who presented the feature and live demo).

You can use this tool as long as your application is running `1_7u40` JVM or higher. To enable the runtime info collection, you need to start JVM with particular flags:

> By default, JFR is disabled in the JVM. To enable JFR, you must launch your Java application with the **-XX:+FlightRecorder** option. Because JFR is a commercial feature, available only in the commercial packages based on Java Platform, Standard Edition (Oracle Java SE Advanced and Oracle Java SE Suite), you also have to enable commercial features using the **-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures** options.

(Quoted http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jfr/about.html#sthref7)

I added this answer as this is viable option for profiling in production IMO.

Also there is an [Eclipse plugin](http://download.oracle.com/technology/products/missioncontrol/updatesites/base/5.2.0/eclipse/) that supports JFR and JMC and capable of displaying information user-friendly.

Comment: The overhead with the default template is about 1%.

Comment: @KireHaglin Even less I thought :)

Comment: Note that these are commercial features requiring you to pay oracle if used in production, as opposed to the traditional JDK which was free to use.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not exactly. This require you to pay Oracle if you're making money with your application using Oracle HotSpot.

Comment: Thanks for bounty award, really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The tools have improved vastly over the years.  These days, most people who have needs like these use a tool that hooks into Java's instrumentation API instead of the profiling API.  Surely there are more examples, but [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com) and [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com) come to mind.  Instrumentation-based solutions usually run as an agent in the JVM and constantly collect data.  They report the data at a higher level (business transaction, web transaction, database transaction) than the old profiling approach and allow you to dig deeper (down to the method or line) if necessary.  You can even setup monitoring and alerts, so you can track/alert on metrics like page load times and performance against SLAs.  With these great tools, you really should have no reason to run a profiler in production any longer.  The cost of running them is negligible.